# How to assign elements to zero if not in a vector in R?

Tags: r

Supposed I have a vector:

```
v <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
v
a b c d 
1 2 3 4
```

I would like to create a new vector, `new_v`, such that: if an element can be found in `v`, it equals to the value in `v`, otherwise assign to `0`. For example, `e`, `f`, and `g` don't exist in `v` and they all are assigned as 0, such that:

```
> new_v
a b c d e f g 
1 2 3 4 0 0 0
```

I know it can be created by `ifelse` for each eletment. Since I have a long vector, I am wondering what the best way to create it.

Comment: `setdiff` could be better `v[setdiff(letters[1:7], names(v))] <- 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setdiff` with the `names` of the vector and assign those to 0 instead of a conditional expression

```
v[setdiff(letters[1:7], names(v))] <- 0
```

-output

```
> v
a b c d e f g 
1 2 3 4 0 0 0
```

Comment: @akrun. Master this approach gives the values but does not give the new names e f g. Why? could you please check? `for(i in ((length(v)+1):length(letters[5:7])))
  +{v = c(v, 0)}`

Comment: @TarJae Perhaps you meant `for(i in ((length(v)+1):length(letters[1:7]))) v <- c(v, setNames(0, letters[i]))` i.e. `5:7` length is only 3, so I changed  to 1:7, and also the values should be named, thus used `setNames` (`=` wouldn't allow expression on the lhs)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `intersect`:

```r
v <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)

new_v <- rep(0, 7)
names(new_v) <- letters[1:7]

new_v[intersect(names(v), names(new_v))] <- v
new_v

#> a b c d e f g 
#> 1 2 3 4 0 0 0
```